# Spanish Characters Not Encoding Correctly

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, pdo

I'm working on a project in the Philippines where many people have special Latin tilde characters in their names.

I have a database set up with all tables in latin1 with latin1_swedish_ci collation.

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                         |
| character_set_connection | latin1                         |
| character_set_database   | latin1                         |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                         |
| character_set_results    | latin1                         |
| character_set_server     | latin1                         |
| character_set_system     | utf8                           |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\xampp\mysql\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

My webpage headers declare iso-8859-1 as the character set.

When I submit an employee name containing a tilde character through my web forms, for example, it appears in my table as 'Marie CaÃ±on' and appears the same on my webpages when I look at the employee's record.

If I change the webpage encoding to utf-8, it displays correctly as 'Marie Cañon'. So, I'm assuming that somehow I'm encoding UTF-8 in my latin1 tables. But I'm confused where that could be occurring.

As far as I know, PDO doesn't deal with encoding. My webpages are declared iso-8859-1, so I'm figuring PHP isn't causing the problem. My character_set_connection is latin1 in MySQL.

Where could this be happening?

Additional Information:
Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS
MySQL 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.9-log
PHP5: 5.3.2
Apache2: 2.2.14

Comment: Ideally you encode everything as UTF-8. Using Latin1 is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 6):

1. Switch your MySQL to utf-8.
2. Install the **mbstring** PHP extension and configure it.
3. Make your PHP headers: `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` and
4. HTMLheaders `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` and
5. check this [cheat sheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet).

Comment: Costis, Thank you for your post! I will look into converting my database to UTF-8 soon. For the time being, I'm hoping to make iso-8859-1 work. As far as I can see, I should be able to have my iso-8859-1 pages send special Spanish characters to a latin1 encoded table. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

this worked for me :

$title = mb_convert_encoding($article['title'], "UTF-8", "iso-8859-1");

for spanish accents